# Update RecyclerView dataset from another class

Tags: android, methods, android-recyclerview

I am trying to update adapter's dataset from another class but with no help. When i am calling the method from inside the RecyclerView class it works but not from outside.

```
private Filters dataFilters = new Filters();
private HomeSpinnerHandler homeSpinnerHandler = new HomeSpinnerHandler(this);
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mHomeAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private static Context context;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private View rootView;
private String homeCompanySelection = null;
private static final String objectTypeProductString = "Product";
private static MaterialDialog dialogHome;
private FloatingActionButton fabHome;
private View viewHome;
private MaterialSpinner spinnerHomeCompany;
private static boolean filterIsCalled = false;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_layout, null);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_refresh);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
    spinnerHomeCompany = (MaterialSpinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerHomeCompany);
    viewHome = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sheetHome);
    context = container.getContext();
    fabHome = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fabhome);
    dialogHome = new MaterialDialog(context);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mHomeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(dataFilters.getAllHomeDataSet());

    PreCachingLayoutManager layoutManager = new PreCachingLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    layoutManager.setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeAdapter);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            updateView();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
    homeSpinnerHandler.addItemsOnCompanySpinner();
    spinnerHomeCompany.setOnItemSelectedListener(homeSpinnerHandler);

    fabHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewHome.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (viewHome != null) {
                ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) viewHome.getParent();
                if (parent != null) {
                    parent.removeView(viewHome);
                }
            }
            dialogHome.setView(viewHome).setPositiveButton("ΑΝΑΖΗΤΗΣΗ", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    companyFilter();
                    dialogHome.dismiss();
                    viewHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("ΑΚΥΡΩΣΗ", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialogHome.dismiss();
                    viewHome.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            dialogHome.show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((RecyclerViewHomeAdapter) mHomeAdapter).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter.MyClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v, int id, String objectType) {

            if (objectType.contains(objectTypeProductString)) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onProductItemClick(id);
            } else {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onPostItemClick(id);
            }
        }
    });
}

public boolean onBackPressed()
{
    if (filterIsCalled){
        Toast.makeText(context,"dsdsd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateView();
        filterIsCalled = false;
    } else
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void companyFilter() {
    homeSpinnerHandler.addItemsOnCompanySpinner();
    mHomeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(dataFilters.getFilteredHomeDataSet(homeCompanySelection));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeAdapter);
    filterIsCalled = true;
}

public void updateView() {
    mHomeAdapter = new RecyclerViewHomeAdapter(dataFilters.getAllHomeDataSet());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mHomeAdapter);
}


public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setHomeCompanySelection(String homeCompanySelection) {
    this.homeCompanySelection = homeCompanySelection;
}

public MaterialSpinner getSpinnerHomeCompany() {
    return spinnerHomeCompany;
}
```

From the other class i am creating an instance

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
```

and calling the method like.

```
homeFragment.updateView();
```

I've also tried using static variables but with no success again.

Answer (score 0):

Do not make it static  or create a new instance of homeFragment.

Try passing a mHomeAdapter to the new class  and updating it there. Also you should not  make a new  adapter. Create a method like this in your adapter:

```
 public void changeData(Data data ) {
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Then call that to change data.

Better yet you can startActivityForResult() and not pass your adapter, or you can create a broadcast receiver in HomeFragment to update the adapter.

Comment: ok passing mHomeAdapter is easy, but how am i going to notify the adapter that data has changed or updated. Currently i am using a tab fragment that is called from MainActivity with drawer. One of the drawer's choice is to update data from server, but it is called from MainActivity. How can i call dataFilters.getAllHomeDataSet() without creating a new instance of adapter. Also every time i tried to use notifyDataSetChanged it was in no use at all. 

A good solution would be to create a broadcast receiver so i can update all the tab fragment's adapter with one call.